# Stack around variable ' ' was corrupted - C

Tags: c, pointers

i'm trying to write a program who concatenates two matrices the same size. It does what i want it to do but i also get an error "Stack around variable 'mc' was corrupted". I can't really figure out how to solve it. Can you please help me?

Here is the code:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TOP     1
#define BOTTOM  2
#define LEFT    3
#define RIGHT   4

int** concatenare_matrice(int **pMat, unsigned char m, unsigned char n, int** pCat, unsigned char mc, unsigned char nc,
    char tip_operatie_concatenare)
{
    // pMat - adresa matrice alocata in mem heap
    // m - nr de linii matrice pMat
    // n - nr de coloane matrice pMat
    // pCat - adresa matrice alocata in mem heap
    // mc - nr de linii matrice pCat
    // nc - nr de coloane matrice pCat
    // tip_operatie_concatenare - tipul de concatenare: TOP (pCat peste pMat), BOTTOM (pMat peste pCat), LEFT (pCat la stanga lui pMat),
    //                                                  RIGHT (pCat la dreapta lui pMat)
    //
    // return: adresa matrice obtinuta prin concatenare, NULL daca nu s-au indeplinit conditiile 

    if (m != mc || n != nc) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (tip_operatie_concatenare == TOP || tip_operatie_concatenare == BOTTOM) {
        // daca tip operatie este top sau bottom, atunci avem o matrice cu nr. de linii = m + mc
        // si nr. coloane = n

        int** pRez = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(n + nc));
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < (n + nc); i++) {
            pRez[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n));
        }

        if (tip_operatie_concatenare == TOP) {
            for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (unsigned char j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    pRez[i][j] = pCat[i][j];
                    pRez[i + m][j] = pMat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        else if(tip_operatie_concatenare == BOTTOM) {
            for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (unsigned char j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    pRez[i][j] = pMat[i][j];
                    pRez[i + m][j] = pCat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return pRez;
    }
    else { // daca tip operatie este left sau right, atunci avem o matrice cu nr. de linii = m
        // si nr. coloane = n + nc
        int** pRez = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*(m));
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            pRez[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(n + nc));
        }

        if (tip_operatie_concatenare == LEFT) {
            for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (unsigned char j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    pRez[i][j] = pCat[i][j];
                    pRez[i][j + n] = pMat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        else if(tip_operatie_concatenare == RIGHT) {
            for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (unsigned char j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    pRez[i][j] = pMat[i][j];
                    pRez[i][j + n] = pCat[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return pRez;
    }

}

int main()
{
    int ** pCat; // matrice alocata in mem heap
    int ** pMat; // matrice alocata in mem heap
    unsigned char m = 2, n = 3; // m nr de linii, n nr de coloane
    unsigned char mc, nc; // mc nr linii pCat, nc nr coloane pCat

    // int Mat[3][3] ---> Mat[i][j]

    // alocare matrice pMat in mem heap 
    pMat = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * m); // alocare vector de adrese de inceput de linii
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++)
        pMat[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n); // alocare vector de elemente aferent liniei i

    // "initializare" elemente
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (unsigned char j = 0; j < n; j++)
            pMat[i][j] = i * 10 + j + 1;

    // alocare si initializare elemente matrice pCat
    printf("Nr linii pCat: ");
    scanf("%ud", &mc);
    printf("Nr coloane pCat: ");
    scanf("%ud", &nc);

    // alocare matrice pCat in mem heap 
    pCat = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * mc);
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < mc; i++)
        pCat[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * nc);
    // "initializare" elemente pCat
    int exemplu = 50;
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < mc; i++)
        for (unsigned char j = 0; j < nc; j++)
            pCat[i][j] = exemplu++;

    // TEMA
    int ** pRez;
    unsigned char mr = 0, nr = 0; // 2 variante
    // mr = 4 si nr = 3 atunci cand tipul este TOP si BOTTOM
    // mr = 2 si nr = 6 atunci cand tipul este LEFT si RIGHT

    char tip_operatie = LEFT;

    pRez = concatenare_matrice(pMat, m, n, pCat, mc, nc, tip_operatie);

    if (pRez == NULL)
    {
        // Matricea rezultat nu s-a creat
        printf("Operatia nu a avut loc!!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // Se calculeaza mr si nr ca dimensiuni ale matrice rezultat pRez din concatenare

        switch (tip_operatie)
        {
        case TOP:
        case BOTTOM:
        {
            mr = mc + m;
            nr = n;
        } break;
        case LEFT:
        case RIGHT:
        {
            mr = m;
            nr = n + nc;
        }
        }

        // Afisare matrice rezultat

        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < mr; i++) {
            for (unsigned char j = 0; j < nr; j++) {
                printf("%d", pRez[i][j]);
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }


    // dezalocare matrice pMat in mem heap
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < m; i++)
        free(pMat[i]); // dezalocare vector cu elemente de pe linia i
    free(pMat); // dezalocare vector de adrese de inceput de linii


    // dezalocare matrice pCat
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < mc; i++)
        free(pCat[i]); // dezalocare vector cu elemente de pe linia i
    free(pCat);

    // dezalocare matrice pRez
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < mr; i++)
        free(pRez[i]); // dezalocare vector cu elemente de pe linia i
    free(pRez);
}
```

So the output is what i want it to be but i can;t seem to understand what the problem is. I have looked up and searched on the internet but i have solved absolutely nothing.

Comment: `scanf("%ud", &mc);` - `mc` is `char`, but you pass it with a format specifier of `unsigned int`. So `scanf` will corrupt the memory around. Same for `nc`. Might be not the only problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you very much, that was the problem! 
Hope you have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marius-Marian Burlacu , What Mr Eugene said seems to be the problem. Here's a more detailed explanation.
char or unsigned char is 1 Byte long. While "Unsigned int" is at least 2 Bytes ( could be 4 on some machines, depends on compiler as well).
So, you are allocating 1 Byte of memory but writing to 2 Bytes or more there by corrupting the stack. You are writing to memory which is not allocate dto "mc" or "nc" variables.

Comment: yes, thank you, that was the problem! instead of writing `%ud` i had to write `%hhu`